# python3 - csv import - changing a string in a for loop

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

I am just trying to remove a few  "" from a csv import.

Sample rows

```
['"fai"', '""', '""', '"190194"',]
['"boo"', '""',]




table = read_csv(FN)
for row in table:
    print (row)
    for item in row:
        edit = item.replace('""','')
        item.replace(item,edit)
```

I have tried many combinations but this is only one i have managed to get to run, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something using list comprehension

```
def dq_strip(string):
    return string.replace('""','')

table = [map(dq_strip, row) for row in table]
```

If @MikeRixWolfe is correct about your intentions, you could replace the two double quote with just one.

Comment: going to see if this works, but would still like to know why my original code is wrong,

Comment: `item.replace(item,edit)` returns a fresh copy of the modified item and never replaces the actual entry in the list.

Comment: ok this works exactly how i wanted it to, but again i dont understand why my other code is wrong. Would never have considered anything like this. Never used map before going to have to try and learn what this does.

Comment: `map(func, list)` is the same as `[func(a) for a in list]`

Comment: @Kuzen, does that answer your questions?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with my original code, pretty happy other than this. cheers for checking back.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex [`sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is one way to do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = [['"fai"', '""', '""', '"190194"',], ['"boo"', '""',]]
>>> unquoted_data = [[re.sub(r'^"|"$', '', s) for s in x] for x in data]
>>> unquoted_data
[['fai', '', '', '190194'], ['boo', '']]
```

Your original code snippet only looks for occurrence of two double quotes together and replaces it with two single quotes. While it works for data like `'""'` it won't work for `'"fai"'`.

The regex above looks for any string that begins or ends with double quotes and replaces it with empty string. Thus giving what you want.

Comment: appreciate this will probably work but i prefer the other solution. Have enough of a head ache without trying to get my head around regex :P I will keep this for reference